# PHP/MYSQL Store large data sets on a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a platform collecting and parsing "csv" files which contains 5000 rows average and 40 columns; files can be uploaded by any registered user so there should be no theoretically limit on how many files can be uploaded and stored (assuming I'm not having more than 20 uploads per day however). These file are being parsed by a custom made PHP parser which is kinda efficient but here comes the problem: storage.
In particular, I would like to store these data in a MySQL db for later use: how should I organize my database? Should I create a table containing a row per file with each cell containing the content of each column of the original file? Or should I insert a single row for every row in the file? 
The first one seems to me kinda better because of the huge number of rows built up by the second solution but also less efficient because any time I have to extract any data in the database, I will have to parse again the whole blob then extract the data I need

Given the fact that i can't store the data in PHP arrays due to lack of memory if too many users connect at the same time, which would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: Do all the CSV files have the same columns?

Comment: The number of rows in a database means pretty much nothing. For almost ANY imaginable solution, storing the data a row per line of CSV will be much better than storing the whole CSV in a single row.

Comment: Yes, the CSV have all the same columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the files have the same columns, you should store them in one table and add another an additional column (possibly referencing a second table with one row per upload) to uniquely identify a set of rows.

E.g.:

```
rowId, setId, col1, col2, ...
1, 1, 'abc', 'def', ...
2, 1, 'abc', 'def', ...
3, 1, 'abc', 'def', ...
4, 2, 'abc', 'def', ...
5, 2, 'abc', 'def', ...
6, 2, 'abc', 'def', ...
```

This is what the data might look like for 2 sets of 3 rows each.

Comment: Let's say 20 files per day, with 3000 lines each (worst case right now), it will generate about 50/60.000 new rows per day which will be about 2 millions rows per month.
It could become a problem in a few months, am I wrong?

Comment: I dunno, depends on what you're trying to do with those rows (explaining that to us would help us answer this question). Either way, storing a table as a row is the wrong way to do it, and doesn't really change the total amount of data that needs to be stored... it only makes the data less efficient to analyze, sort, etc., and makes me wonder why you're trying to use a database.

What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: I'd say the same thing. first of all, 40 columns doesn't seem like too much to me. As for storage of your data, that all depends on your server storage limit (which can always be upgraded with almost no limit) and the need to search/parse this data. If, once stored, it's rarely accessed, you won't need to worry about performance issues. You could also store a reference to the csv file in the database, and keep the csv in the filesystem.

Comment: Basically, the data is composed by a series of latlng points where each point contains some additional data (let's say data1...dataN) related to that coordinate.
When the user select a point on a map it should show the data related to that coord to the user (basically that's the idea)

Comment: WHAT do you want to do WITH the data? I don't really care what the data is.

Comment: 2mill a month could be a walk in the park or cripple you, we know nothing of your hardware\software\hosting.

Comment: Well, in that case what I suggested is fine, and you want to create a two-column database index on the long/lat columns, so that searching and ordering by those columns is fast. You still definitely want to keep the data rows as table rows and not compress them in any way.

Comment: (misclick enter in the meanwhile). 
However, I'm not expecting to have the data accessed trillions of times, I suppose it will be uploaded, stored and rarely accessed. 
Also, let's suppose a -decent- hosting service; not the Google farm neither the crappy $9.90/year discount provider

Comment: 2 million a month is generally fine, as long as you index the columns you need to search on. You might need to upgrade your server or something after a few years, or delete old data, or break up the data onto multiple servers, but I would just go with 2 million a month until it gets slow (will take a long time on a decent server), then solve that problem separately.